# How to convert SWIG object to python?

Tags: python, swig, quickfix

I am working with the QuickFIX python library. It is made using SWIG. I am trying to get string outputs of the functions I am calling from the library, but I keep getting outputs like this -

```
<Swig Object of type 'std::set< FIX::SessionID > *' at 0x00000265E1C15BD0>
```

I am not familiar with SWIG and how to work with it at all. I am trying to learn how to work with it. But I cannot figure out how to use it inside my Django modules.

Would be really grateful if someone could suggest how I can achieve what I am trying to do.

Comment: The most recent commit they added looks like it was intended to support `std::set<FIX::SessionID>`: https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/commit/fc98faf028971159d69a590e1397a9a43905ba19

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about `FIX` but I have used SWIG to wrap some C & C++ libraries for Python. The `<Swig Object of type 'std::set< FIX::SessionID > *' at 0x00000265E1C15BD0>` you have *is* a Python object. It's a SWIG-generated Python wrapper for a `std::set` of `FIX::SessionID`. It should have some / most / all of the methods and attributes of the C++ object. In your Python interpreter you can use `dir(obj)` to see what those attributes are. If you're lucky then `help(obj)` will give you some useful documentation of them.